# blocked contacts in contact list IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift4, contacts, contact-list

My App requires access to the contact list. I was able to fetch contacts from my contact list and I populated a tableview with contact list however, I am facing a problem. My contact list includes users that are blocked on iphone. Is there is a way to check if the contact is blocked or no in my swift code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found an answer to my problem. I found that the blocked contact are have a first name called spam. I filtered out the names that are called spam from contact list

Comment: Are you sure, that Apple is setting that value to "spam"? I couldn't verify that.

Comment: I found that on my device try to print the names and see

Comment: This usually happens when you have some calling helper app like Truecaller, it marks malicious contacts as SPAM and puts all of them under same name or group in the contacts app.

Comment: that might be true I don't rememeber if i had true caller or no. Do you know any other method to check for blocked contacts